# Date from Spring to web as timestamp using Jakson

Tags: java, json, angularjs, spring, jackson

I have `Match` class and field `Date start`. My goal is get start as timestamp. I use Spring, AngularJs, and jackson as json converter.

Spring Controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/web2/getMatch", method =RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Match  getPicksHistory() {
        PickDAO pd = new PickDAO();
        return pd.getMatch();  
    }
```

On AgularJS controler:

```
var res = $http.post(urlSer.url+"web2/getMatch");
    res.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // now returns data.start = "Aug 8, 2015 7:00:00 PM"
        // My goal is get as timestamp
    });
```

Comment: "Aug 8, 2015 7:00:00 PM" *is* a timestamp. If you want to format it differently you'll need to show the definition `Match` class and type of its `start` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by 'timestamp' you mean a numeric timestamp as opposed to a textual representation. You can use a custom `ObjectMapper`:

```
@Component
@Primary
public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {
    public CustomObjectMapper() {
        configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use jackson-databind:2.6.1 and `JsonSerializer`

```
@Component
public class JsonDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date>{

   @Override
   public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator gen,
        SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException,
        JsonProcessingException {
    gen.writeNumber(date.getTime());
   }

}
```

Comment: Is there any advantage over the solution I posted?

Comment: No I found  it before your answer :)